# Writing a Function for finding the sum in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Write a function windowPosSum(int[] a, int n) that replaces each element a[i] with the sum of a[i] through a[i + n], but only if a[i] is positive valued. If there are not enough values because we reach the end of the array, we sum only as many values as we have.

For example, suppose we call windowPosSum with the array a = {1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 4}, and n = 3. In this case, we’d:

```
Replace a[0] with a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3].
Replace a[1] with a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4].
Not do anything to a[2] because it’s negative.
Replace a[3] with a[3] + a[4] + a[5].
Replace a[4] with a[4] + a[5].
Not do anything with a[5] because there are no values after a[5].
```

Thus, the result after calling windowPosSum would be {4, 8, -3, 13, 9, 4}.

What I've written, so far:

public class BreakContinue {

public static void windowPosSum(int[] a, int n) {

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1){

sum = sum + a[i + n];

}

return(sum);

}

How can I find the sum of the array, sticking to the parameters of the function?

Comment: Please add a tag to specify what language you are programming in.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be returning a new int array rather than just one int and your method can't be void since you are returning a value. Instead of void, you should write int[] as that is the type of value you are returning. I believe this code does what you are asking. Hope this helps!

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 4};
    int n = 3;
    int[] sum = sum(nums,n);
    for(int i=0; i<sum.length; i++){
      System.out.println(sum[i]);
    }
  }
  public static int[] sum(int[] a,int n){
    int[] b = a;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      if(a[i]>0){
        for(int j=i+1; j<=i+n; j++){
          if(j>=a.length){
            break;
          }
          b[i] = b[i]+a[j];
        }
      }
    }
    return b;
  }
}
```